# Definition of unit angle

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Let $\theta$ be the (smallest) angle between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't understand about the notation $\hat\theta$. Is it "unit" angle? If so, the how do we define it?

**Context:** Let $\mathbf{r}$ vector in the lower half plane of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a function of time, i.e. $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(t)$, $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ be the corresponding unit vector. Define $\theta$ be the (smallest) angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and $y$-axis. Hence we have $\theta$ is also a function of time. Then we have

$$\dot{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}=\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}.$$

Comment: what is the smallest angle?

Comment: The one which is less than or equal to $\pi$

Comment: I think we need more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat \theta$ is the unit vector pointing "in the direction of the rotation", so to speak. See this image, where $r$ is the vector being expressed in polar coordinates ($\hat \theta$ is called $i_{\theta}$ in the picture).

In terms of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$, the $\hat{\theta}$ that is used in polar coordinates is defined as $$\hat{\theta}=-\sin(\theta)\hat{x} + \cos(\theta)\hat{y}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle of the vector with the $x$-axis, also shown in the picture.

[image]